# Splice function freezes program

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a multiple choice quiz wherein a user inputs their own questions and answers and develops a quiz. I'm having trouble creating a button that when clicked deletes one of the questions stored in the array. This is what i have so far... any help would be appreciated.

```
bodyText = bodyText + '<input type="button" id="btnDeleteQuestion" 
  value="Delete a question" onClick="questionBank.splice(2,1)">';
```

What I'm having trouble with ^^^^

```
 function initialiseQuiz() {
    var bodyText = '<h1>Multichoice quiz</h1><h2>Quiz Setup</h2>';
if(questionBank.length == 0) {
    bodyText = bodyText + '<p>There are no questions defined.  
      Please define at least one question.</p>';
}
else {
    bodyText = bodyText + '<p>Questions currently in the question bank:</p>';
    bodyText = bodyText + '<ul>';
    for(var i=0; i<questionBank.length;i++) {
        bodyText = bodyText + '<li>' + 
            questionBank[i]['questionText'] + '</li>';
    }
    bodyText = bodyText + '</ul>';
    bodyText = bodyText + 
        '<p>Create the quiz, delete or add more questions. </p>';

}

bodyText = bodyText + '<input type="button" id="btnDefineQuestion" 
    value="Define a question" onClick="defineQuestion(' + 
        questionBank.length +', 1);" />';

if(questionBank.length > 0) {
    bodyText = bodyText + '<input type="button" 
        id="btnCreateQuiz" value="Create the quiz"   
        onClick="displayQuestions(
            document.getElementById(\'cmbNumQuestions\').value);" />';
    bodyText = bodyText + '<input type="button" id="btnDeleteQuestion" 
        value="Delete a question" onClick="questionBank.splice(2,1)">';
    bodyText = bodyText + '<p><label for="cmbNumQuestions">
        Choose how many questions to display: </label>';
    bodyText = bodyText + '<select id="cmbNumQuestions">';


        for(var i=0;i<questionBank.length;i++) {
            bodyText = bodyText + '<option value="' + Number(i+1) +'" ';

            if(i==questionBank.length-1) bodyText = bodyText + 
                'selected="selected" ';

            bodyText = bodyText + '>' + Number(i+1)  +'</option>';
        }

    bodyText = bodyText + '</select></p>';
}
    document.body.innerHTML = bodyText;

}
```

Comment: Could you show what you are trying to do to delete a question, your `splice()` function?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is delete the third question stored in the array

Comment: It's hard to understand what part of your code is not working, `splice(2,1)` should delete the third question from the array. Is that what you are trying to do or you also need to delete it from the DOM?

Comment: This code works as expected. Add console.log('Bank Length: ' +questionBank.length) after splice and you will see. You are not deleting DOM elements, but it is not freeze at all.